# How can I install a custom payment gateway in Expresso Store 2.1

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

I have (had) a custom payment gateway running in Expresso Store 2.0.6. Since i updated to 2.1 the gateway is not working anymore. I am aware of the new folder structure inside the vendor/omnipay folder and tried to adapt my own gateway folder without success. The gateway is not listed in stores payment gateway settings. I also changed the store_unofficial_payment_gateways value in the db from 0 to 1.

So,

- Are there some special installation instructions for custom payment gateways in EE Store 2.1? Or is it like in previous versions that i only have to move my custom gateway folder into the vendor folder and if everything is fine in my folder the gateway shows up?
- Are there other files i have to adapt outside my custom gateway folder?
- What's about that new composer.json file? I'm not sure how that should look like …

Also worth to note: The button "Add Payment Method" in the upper right corner doesn't exists in my installation as seen in the store docs: https://exp-resso.com/docs/settings_payment_methods.html

I am running the latest versions from both EE and Expresso Store.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As of Store 2.1 gateways are now added as separate extensions outside of the actual Store folders. This makes it easier in the future to upgrade Store because you don't have to worry about overwriting your custom gateway. (Last item under [Developer](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_210)). You can see an example of the folder structure in the example gateway [Store Check](https://github.com/expressodev/store_check).

Comment: Since the "Store Check" example is so basic, I also suggest checking out my [Beanstream gateway](https://github.com/amphibian/store-beanstream) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on Justin's answer a little, payment gateways in Store 2.1 can now be registered as separate extensions. This means you don't need to copy anything into the `third_party/store` folder or worry about re-copying files when you upgrade.

The extension hook you need to use is called `store_payment_gateways`. If you are unfamiliar with ExpressionEngine extension development, it's probably worth reviewing the [extension development guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html) first.

Inside the extension hook, you need to first add your gateway name to Store's list of gateways, then tell Store where to find your gateway files (so they can be autoloaded when needed). Here is a complete example:

```
/**
 * This hook is called when Store is searching for available payment gateways
 * We will use it to tell Store about our custom gateway
 */
public function store_payment_gateways($gateways)
{
    // tell Store about our new payment gateway
    // (this must match the name of your gateway in the Omnipay directory)
    $gateways[] = 'Check';

    // tell PHP where to find the gateway classes
    // Store will automatically include your files when they are needed
    $composer = require(PATH_THIRD.'store/autoload.php');
    $composer->add('Omnipay', __DIR__);

    return $gateways;
}
```

For a complete example, check out these existing third-party gateways:

- [Check](https://github.com/expressodev/store_check) - our example custom gateway which simply creates an additional "Manual" payment gateway
- [Beanstream](https://github.com/amphibian/store-beanstream) by Derek Hogue

Comment: That's wat i call first class support. Answering a question on December 24th. Thanks Adrian & Justin. I will try that. Merry Christmas!